Vary how transparency applies to different objects within a container
I'd like to develop an infographic-style image render where I have a semi-transparent object that contains a number of other objects. Is there any way to adjust how the transparency of the containing object is applied to each object within?
Basically I want to make the container 50% transparent, but I'd like to make one of the objects within completely unobscured, so it stands out visually.

Hello, are you using Eevee or Cycles ? Bender primarily uses physically-based rendering techniques so this might not be trivial to do in a regular scene. You can however leverage view layers to composite some objects on top of others to make them stand out.

Thank you. I am happy to use either really - whatever gets the job done! My preference would be cycles though.
